# [Yew-router]use_navigator() is None

Tags: rust, yew

I'm a beginner. I tried to using yew-router with confirming the below tutorial.
https://yew.rs/docs/next/concepts/router

but, it's not working.
I'm getting the below error message.

**panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/main.rs:17:37**

A part of my code is below.
yew's version is 0.20, and yew-router's version is 0.17.

```
use yew::prelude::*;
use yew_router::prelude::*;


#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Routable)]
enum Route {
    #[at("/")]
    App,
    ..
}

#[function_component(App)]
fn app() -> Html {
  let navigator = use_navigator().unwrap();
   ..
}
```

I know that Navigator is None, but I don't know why is that and how to solve it.

Comment: Do you have [one of the router components](https://docs.rs/yew-router/latest/yew_router/router/index.html) (`Router`, `BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter`) as a parent?

Comment: Thanks to you, this issue is resolved! I didn't have them.

Answer (score 2):

As below, this issue is resolved after adding tag in parent component.(main.rs)

```rust
use page::sample_page::SamplePage;
use page::home_page::Home;
use yew::prelude::*;
use yew_router::prelude::*;

mod page;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Routable)]
pub enum Route {
    #[at("/")]
    Home,
    #[at("/sample_page")]
    SamplePage,
}

fn switch(routes: Route) -> Html {
    match routes {
        Route::Home => html! {
            <Home />
        },
        Route::SamplePage => html! {
        <SamplePage/>
        },
    }
}

#[function_component(App)]
fn app() -> Html {
    html! {
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch<Route> render={switch} />
        </BrowserRouter>
    }
}

fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

The top page is shown below.(home_page.rs)

In this example, when you click `sample`, you see sample page.

```rust
use yew::prelude::*;
use yew_router::prelude::*;

use crate::Route;

#[function_component(Home)]
pub fn home() -> Html {
    let navigator = use_navigator().unwrap();

    let go_sample_page_button = {
        let navigator = navigator.clone();
        let onclick = Callback::from(move |_| navigator.push(&Route::SamplePage));
        html! {
            <button type="button" onclick={onclick} >{ "sample" }</button>
        }
    };

    html! {
      <>
        {go_sample_page_button}
      </>
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call your `let navigator = ...` code now? Can you post a listing? (It seems that just having this beneath BrowserRouter isn't sufficient, for me it only works if called from code within a sub-_component_).

Comment: @bk138 
I added to the code above now. My current code is like above.